# Comparing two arrays of objects, and exclude the elements does not match any of the value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Here, I have one `array1` from redux where I will show these four objects to user. Here user can update any of the value or may not update.
So here I only want to send the object in array which are updated (any of the value is updated). In `stateVariable`, I will have same array object but with changed values.

```
var array1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var stateVariable = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra123'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'admin', username:'be_bob'}
];
```

Ex:
in stateVariable array, where `id:1, username:'sandra123'` is changed and for `id:4  type:'admin'` is changed. So in input request to backend api, I wanted to send only array which has change values.

```
Expected : 

var requestData = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra123'}
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'admin', username:'be_bob'}
];
```

Can you please suggest any approach to implement on FE react before making backend api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over one of the arrays, search for the respective id in the other array and check if the objects are equal or not ...

```
function userequals(u1, u2) {
  //function to determine whether two objects are equal
  //note, this will not work correctly if userproperties
  //are objects or arrays themselves 
  for (let k in u1) {
    if (u1[k] !== u2[k]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

let requestdata = stateData.filter(u1 => {
  let u2 = array1.find(x => x.id == u1.id);

  return !userequals(u1, u2);
})
```

If both of your arrays are guaranteed to have the same structure (ie same length and elements at the same index represent the same user) you can simplify

```
let requestdata = stateData.filter((u1, i) => !userequals(u1, array1[i]));
```

Comment: Yes, it will have the same structure.